# in landscape no showing image and button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have added one imageview, 2 button in one view controller in code. In portrait mode its working well. But in landscape mode not able to see the image and button.

```
@implementation ViewController {
    UIImageView* imgView; // your UIImageView
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    UIImage* img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.jpg"];
    UIImage* img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"s2.jpg"];


    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; // create a UIImageView with the same size as the view.
    imgView.animationImages = @[img1, img2]; // use a nice NSArray literal to pass in your images.
    imgView.animationDuration = 2.0*2.0; // 2 seconds for each image (x3 images)
    [self.view addSubview:imgView]; // add UIImageView to view

    [imgView startAnimating]; // start animating

 // button one
    UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width/2 , 50.0)];

    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:188/255.0f green:155/255.0f blue:211/255.0f alpha:0.6f]];

    [button setTitle:@"Sign Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // title color
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

  // Button Two
    UIButton* button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width/2 , 50.0)];

   [button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:188/255.0f green:155/255.0f blue:211/255.0f alpha:0.6f]];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Sign In" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // title color
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
    // Border color for one button
    UIView *leftBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1, 1, button.frame.size.height)];
    leftBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:237/255.0f green:211/255.0f blue:246/255.0f alpha:0.6f];
    [button1 addSubview:leftBorder];

}
```

Why its not working well for landscape. Please help me, for portrait its working well. For landscape its not working ..

Comment: You will either need to 1) create this view in interface builder and add some constraints, 2) add constraints programmatically, or 3) if your opposed to using auto layout, you can detect orientation change and re-assign the frames of your objects to reflect the orientation

Answer (score 0):

It's not working in landscape because when we rotate to landscape the button and image view, as you have positioned them in your code, are located below the bottom of the screen.

Comment: now i added uimage in story board...when i again opened my 1.png image is filke fully fetched, not looking gud than in portraint. And alos my butoon not at all showing, it went down

Comment: its there any possible to make image gud and for both portrait and landscape mode

Comment: Yes. Position them using layout constraints, not by setting their frame.

Comment: ok. Now i have two set image  as i mention in my code 11.jpg, s2.jpg....Now i need to use this two image for portrait. And a1.jpg, a2.jpg image for landscape. Can you explain me in some example code for that

Comment: @user5513630 Your question was "Why its not working well for landscape" and I answered that. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement Auto Layout. It will fix the problem. Please avoid hard coding the positions as will create problems in UI. If you want to hard code the points then make your app in either portrait mode or landscape mode.

In auto layout constraints can be set programmatically as well. Just check which is feasible for you and implement it.